Unable to Create New User in Guacamole Server using API
I'm trying to create a new user in my Guacamole server hosted on localhost:8080 using its API.
I've successfully obtained an API token using the following command:
export TOKEN=$(curl -s -k -X POST http://localhost:8080/guacamole/api/tokens -d 'username=guacadmin&password=guacadmin' | jq -r .authToken)

However, when I attempt to create a new user using the following curl command:
curl -s -k -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content Type: application/json" http://localhost:8080/guacamole/api/session/users --data-binary '{ "username": "newuser", "password": "testpassword", "attributes": {} }'

I receive the following error message:
{ "message": "Unexpected internal error", "translatableMessage": { "key": "APP.TEXT_UNTRANSLATED", "variables": { "MESSAGE": "Unexpected internal error" } }, "statusCode": null, "expected": null, "type": "INTERNAL_ERROR" }

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue or suggest what might be causing this error?

I use MYSQL to create the new Users. Maybe this is an alternative for you.
Something like this will do:
-- Generate salt, set @dis to 0 to activate account
SET @salt = UNHEX(SHA2(UUID(), 256));
SET @dis = '1';

-- Create base entity entry for user
INSERT INTO guacamole_entity (name, type)
VALUES ('user1', 'USER');

-- Create user and hash password with salt
INSERT INTO guacamole_user (
    entity_id,
    password_salt,
    password_hash,
    password_date,
    disabled
)
SELECT
    entity_id,
    @salt,
    UNHEX(SHA2(CONCAT('user1', HEX(@salt)), 256)),
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    @dis
FROM guacamole_entity
WHERE
    name = 'user1'
    AND type = 'USER';

It will create the user: user1 with password user1 and deactivate the account at the beginning.
I also use mysql for creation of connections and the bonding of one connection to one user that should use this connection.
I find this quite elegant.
